# Not able to find application by app name in Playstore

Tags: android, google-play

It has been almost 15 days but I am not able to find my application by app name in Playstore.

I am able to find the application by package name.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: So, if you published the app kindly check it in your `Google Play Developer Account` that it is got published yet or not. Then it will be great to search the app with package name or name on the `Play Store`

Comment: Hello, Yah it is already published and I am also able to find the application by app package name but not able to search app by app name.

Comment: could you provide more details about the same?

Comment: My application name is `TruSportsman` try to search with app name. Then try with Package name : `com.trusportsman.android`

Comment: I found see here -: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trusportsman.android

Comment: @kdblue How you found using app name or package name?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani I am god ;) kidding, it's simple on the web(play store) search working package name.

Comment: @kdblue Yes I know that, If I search using app name, I am not getting my app in the list, but If I do it with package name. It is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a developer and have just released your app, it can happen because Google Play needs some time to index your app to add it to search results. Try to search your app later (in 4-5 hours). E.g., for App Store, it takes around 24 hours.

If you are a user and want to find an app it can happen because of several factors:

- **Device capability** (some apps are compatible only with specific devices depending on phone model, OS version, screen resolution, etc.);
- **Location** (some developers make their apps only available to particular countries);
- **Publishing status** (some apps are only accessible by a direct link to it. Developers do it for closed tests, etc.)
- **Keyword rank [very rare]** (sometimes the app that you are looking for can be indexed low by the Google Play, and you will have a list of competitors above your app. To solve this issue - try to search by app name, but sometimes even this doesn’t help).

[Source](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-I-find-the-app-when-searching-by-its-name-in-Google-Play-Store-though-it-is-listed)